# Can I change the alignment of my intelligent item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, alignment

I am a chaotic neutral ranger who has a belt of physical might that I dropped a lot of gold to have my sorcerer make for me.  He rolled a natural 20 so the GM imbued it with sentience and rolled that it is lawful good and wants to destroy arcane spell casters.  Most of the time it doesn't interfere and provides great comic relief.

However, now I am at odds with the belt and it has sprouted legs, believes I am evil, and wants to take me out of combat and throw me into a pit of lava.  Is there any way to change its alignment to chaotic neutral or disimbue its sentience without erasing my stat bonuses?

Comment: Vaguely related: [Intelligent magic items in *D&D 3.5.*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/45801/8610)

Comment: Ask the sorcerer for a refund. I'm sure your ranger can be convincing.

Comment: Reading the link posted by BBlake, I don't see "sprouts legs and tries to throw its owner into lava" listed as a typical result of an ego conflict, not even under "extreme circumstances". What did you *do* to that poor belt to deserve such treatment, anyway?

Comment: I ignored the belt's suggestion to help another PC, who I believed had his situation handled, while continuing to attack a foe I had a score to settle with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Only if you're cool with Randy, the Magic-Loving Demon Belt

> [Helm of Opposite Alignment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items#TOC-Helm-of-Opposite-Alignment):
>   When placed upon the head, this item's curse immediately takes effect (Will DC 15 negates). On a failed save, the alignment of the wearer is radically altered to an alignment as different as possible from the former alignment—good to evil, chaotic to lawful, neutral to some extreme commitment (LE, LG, CE, or CG). Alteration in alignment is mental as well as moral, and the individual changed by the magic thoroughly enjoys his new outlook. A character who succeeds on his save can continue to wear the helmet without suffering the effect of the curse, but if he takes it off and later puts it on again, another save is required.
>
> Only a wish or a miracle can restore a character's former alignment, and the affected individual does not make any attempt to return to the former alignment. In fact, he views the prospect with horror and avoids it in any way possible. If a character of a class with an alignment requirement is affected, an atonement spell is needed as well if the curse is to be obliterated. When a helm of opposite alignment has functioned once, it loses its magical properties.

Put the helmet on the belt, which changes its alignment, as per the above quoted text.
Of course, some GMs will rule that this is 'mind-affecting' (though, RAW, it's not), so for full effect it should be preceded by [Polymorph Any Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object) to give the belt a type more amiable to subjugation.  In any case, you'll need to give it a head, but that can be done much cheaper (such as via alter self).  Being LG, the belt's alignment will permanently change to CE, and the polymorph effects can then be safely dismissed.

I make no guarantees that your new belt-friend will be *less* likely to hurl you off into nearby lava pits.

---

Note: Polymorph Any Object does not work on magical objects in general, but it *does* work on [intelligent items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/intelligent-items); they also count as constructs and the spell *can* target constructs

Comment: The text says, "Intelligent items can actually be considered creatures because they have Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. Treat them as constructs," but it never says to *consider* or *treat* intelligent items as constructs *for what purposes.* Intelligent items, for instance, don't have feats or skill points, so it's not *for **all** purposes.* A warning that this is up to the DM might be in order.

Comment: (I know I shouldn't care, but letting the spell *polymorph any object* bypass its no magic items restriction means for a flat 2,400 gp any *Pathfinder* item can occupy any magic item slot (search for [Altering Existing Magic Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Items-Slots)). I am almost certain that wasn't [Cooke's intent](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/intelligentItems.htm), but, y'know, whatever. The intelligent magic items rules have always been a bit of a mess.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Wait they don't get feats and skills?

Comment: They lack Hit Dice. See this [question and answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45726/8610) for more about intelligent items.

Comment: I really liked this answer.  Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 9):

Considering this item is unique to your campaign, and was given sentience by your GM. I'd say try to roleplay out a conclusion with the sorcerer that made it. For example capture the belt now that it has legs, take it to the sorcerer and see what he can do. The GM might let him make another craft roll to try and change the alignment of the belt, or if he fails it might make the belt even more troublesome. Or more likely he won't the sorcerer won't be able to fix it and you may end up on side quest to find someone to deal with this belt, like a LG paladin might be able to help you with it. Either way just try to have some fun with your LG belt.

Comment: Or, failing that, sell the belt to the paladin and buy a less troublesome item instead.

Comment: Additionally, an out-of-character conversation with the GM might be in order: "this belt is nifty, but I feel it's gotten away from being fun comic relief and is bordering on the obnoxious; how can we work together to bring back the quirky and lose the 'throw me into a lake of lava'?".

Comment: Oh, I enjoyed the banter.  It made the campaign fun and we still talked about it today.  Prompted me to come back and look at what I posted.   Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

### By the RAW, No

There are no rules in the RAW which allow one to change an [intelligent magic item's](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/intelligentItems.html) alignment.  Once it is created, that is what it is and will not change.  Your only option is that your GM will allow a house rule/overrule that will allow you to somehow do this in game (as Iankill suggested).

If he doesn't go for that, I would say that in the end, the item's benefits, whatever they are, are not worth the 1-3 negative levels you should be taking by using an intelligent magic item of a different alignment.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

### But you can somewhat bend it to your own will.

> When an item has an Ego of its own, it has a will of its own. The item
>   is absolutely true to its alignment. **If the character who possesses
>   the item is not true to that alignment's goals or the item's special
>   purpose, personality conflict—item against character—results.**
>   Similarly, any item with an Ego score of 20 or higher always considers
>   itself superior to any character, and **a personality conflict results
>   if the possessor does not always agree with the item.**
>
> **When a personality conflict occurs, the possessor must make a Will
>   saving throw (DC = item's Ego)**. If the possessor succeeds, she is
>   dominant. If she fails, the item is dominant. Dominance lasts for 1
>   day or until a critical situation occurs (such as a major battle, a
>   serious threat to either the item or the character, and so on). Should
>   an item gain dominance, it resists the character's desires and demands
>   concessions such as any of the following: [Items Against Characters](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/intelligentItems.html#items-against-characters)

*Emphasis mine*

So - You'll have to determine the ego score of the item and at the beginning of battle (a critical situation) you'll have to assert your dominance with a Will save. After that it shouldn't try to kill you for about a day (or until the next critical situation).

Comment: I liked this answer a lot.  Thanks for the thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

There's not a stock item or spell that does this.  In the Wrath of the Righteous Adventure Path, there is an evil "Corruption Forge" used to make evil items that the PCs can convert over via lots of hallow spells and crafting work into a Purity Forge and then use to make evil intelligent items good - we are reworking the evil weapon [Soulshear](http://karzoug.info/srd/magicItems/weapons/SpecificWeapons/Soulshear.htm) into a holy weapon using it.  But that's an example of how hard this kind of thing is (artifact level stuff).

But really, it sounds like your GM is just making stuff up and having fun and not being bound by the rules, which is fine - your solution is to work with him in and out of game to figure out what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume a *wish* would do it, unless your DM is particularly stingy or the item is supposed to be semi-artefact level in power. There's one way to find out...